# Data not showing in Firestore Emulator UI for Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm using firestore at the local environment using Emulator Suite and am able to successfully read and write data on my Flutter app. But in a scenario where I use

```
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(message.from)
          .collection(message.to)
          .add({
        'from': message.from,
        'to': message.to,
        'text': message.text,
        'time': message.time,
        'isSent': message.isSent,
        'isRead': message.isRead
      });
```

data is stored and retrieved successfully. But the problem is I'm not able to see it in Emulator UI. On the app, it's working fine, but why is it not showing up in the interface?

Even other data that I store normally using `collection('data').set({...})` it shows up in UI, but not it's same in the above case.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you use Emulator ? What do you configure in flutter to communicate in local network? May be add more information in your post.

Comment: Yes, I use the Flutter emulator suite for local development. What more info do you need?

Comment: May be your firebase configuration for using in local developement because it need some code lines and configuration. Because If I understand your ptoblem, you can read/add datas via UI app but you see nothing on Firestore Emulator UI.

Comment: I've also mentioned that I can view other data that have not subcollections.

Comment: Ok sorry . I don't understand because there's so many UI ( UI app, simulator app ..) may be it's because of this bug : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools-ui/issues/273

Comment: tried, still not working

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution. Have same issue

Comment: @VinayakaramNagarajan issue is still there. To view subcollection data in the emulator, you can create a similar subcollection manually in UI, then other already present data will reflect.